# How to run a group by in AWS Cloud Watch Logs Insights

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have CWL Entries as below. Showing entries in SQL Type for clarity

```
Name City
1     Chicago
2     Wuhan
3     Chicago
4     Wuhan
5     Los Angeles
```

Now I want to get below output

```
City         Count
Chicago        2
Wuhan          2
Los Angeles    1
```

Is there a way I can run `GROUP BY` in CWL Insights.

Pseudo Query

```
Select Count(*), City From {TableName} GROUP BY City
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use the aggregation function `count` with the `by` statement: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html

Here is a full example for your case, assuming the logs contain the entries exactly as you have in the example (regex for city name is very simple, you may want to refine that).

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| parse @message /^(?<number>\d+)\s+(?<city>[a-zA-Z\s]+)$/
| filter ispresent(city)
| stats count(*) by city
```

Result:

```
---------------------------
|     city     | count(*) |
|--------------|----------|
| Chicago      | 2        |
| Wuhan        | 2        |
| Los Angeles  | 1        |
---------------------------
```

Comment: Good query! Is there a way to give an alias to count(*), similar to sql where aliasing can be used?

Comment: You can use `as` in a similar way you would in sql: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html#CWL_QuerySyntax-alias

Comment: @Nida you just do | stats count(*) as counts by city

Comment: is there any way of simple group by query. I mean I do not want the aggregation like count, sum, avg etc. Like taking above example it will only return data grouped by cities. So that I can get all the names of from each city.

Comment: You can do the aggregation and the just drop the numbers. Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72309353/how-to-show-only-unique-rows-in-cloudwatch-output/72330000#72330000